# Understanding HTML Form Element behavior

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've a form with few textfields and a submit button. A submit handler is attached to the form in order to validate the form before submission. Additionally, the handler is supposed to show an OK message to the user, and finally to redirect to the front page.

Validation works fine, but when the validation succeeds, the OK message is shown only briefly or not at all, and the page is refreshed instead of redirection.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <input name="firstname">
    <input name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="hidden v-ok">Validation OK</div>
<div class="hidden v-failed">Validation failed</div>
```

And the related JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    const controls = Array.from(form.elements),
        valid = controls.every(control => control.value !== '');
    if (!valid) {
        // Validation failed, don't submit
        e.preventDefault();
        // Show ValidationFailed message
        const message = document.querySelector('.hidden.v-failed');
        message.classList.remove('hidden');
        return;
    }
    // Validation OK, show message and submit
    const message = document.querySelector('.hidden.v-ok');
    message.classList.remove('hidden');
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }, 2000);
});
```

I've also tried to redirect without the timeout, but the result is the same, the page is only refreshed, it never navigates to the front page. What can I do to get my form posted and still able to see the message and do the redirection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Showing the message and redirecting later provides the document location to stay on the current page. You can't submit a form and stay on the current page. Use AJAX aka XMLHttpRequest to send the data to your server instead of submitting a form.

### How HTMLFormElement works

On early days, before JavaScript existed, form element was purposed to send data from a page to a server, then the server handled the data, and responded with a new page, which was loaded by the browser. Even today, browsers are doing exactly this same when a form is submitted.

[The standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element) says:

> "*The form element **represents a hyperlink** that can be manipulated through a collection of form-associated elements*" (emphasis mine).

Now, if you're not interested in a deeper explanation of how the form submission works under the hood, you can scroll down to the **All this in practice** chapter.

But what actually happens when a submit button is clicked? The standard defines a [Form submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm), which is very deeply detailed, and is a bit hard to follow. Here are the strongly simplified main steps:

1. Browser checks whether the form can be submitted (document fully active, sandboxing etc.), failing the check cancels the algorithm
2. Validation defined by the elements' attributes is executed, if validation fails the algorithm is cancelled
3. The attached submit event(s) are executed (attached event(s) can fire only once)
4. If any of the submit handlers called `event.preventDefault` the algorithm is cancelled
5. The encoding of the form is set
6. An entry list of the form control elements is created
7. Various attributes of the form are parsed (ex. action defaults to the URL of the form's document if the attribute is not set)
8. The internal sending method is selected based on `method` attribute of the form (defaults to GET) and the schema of the URL in `action` attribute
9. A *navigation plan* is created (a task) and send to the event queue (includes the deformed form data)
10. The task in the event queue is executed, and navigation to a new page takes place

In the real algorithm, a lot more of actions are executed, ex. step 1 is executed between many of the steps, and the algorithm prevents concurrent submissions. Also, the described algorithm stands only when an actual submit button is activated. If the submission is called via JS by `form.submit` method, steps 2 - 4 are jumped over.

The above algorithm explains how JS form validation in submit event handler can cancel the submission (#4). The [unload document process](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unloading-document-cleanup-steps) (#10) explains how the timeout is broken when a new page is about to load (all the pending timers and events are aborted). But, any of these doesn't actually explain, how `location.href` in a submit event handler is ignored without the timeout.

The answer to this question is hidden in the definition of the form: It "*represents a hyperlink*". Activating a hyperlink sets a specific internal [navigation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigate) event, and an internal "ongoing-navigation" flag. Any later activation of any hyperlink checks that flag, and is cancelled if the flag was set. Setting `location.href` is not actually a hyperlink, but [it uses](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-href) the same navigation mechanisms, hence it's also cancelled, if a pending navigation is detected. It's notable, that calling `event.preventDefault` in a **submit** handler unsets the "ongoing-navigation" flag immediately, which makes setting `location.href` to work again later in the handler.

<sup>(The navigation behavior described above is heavily simplified. To fully understand how the browser navigation works, provides deep knowledge of the event queues and navigation process, which are described in the standard (details being even partially implementation-dependent), but these are not the objective of this answer.)</sup>

### All this in practice

As the most of the previously described actions of HTML Form are executed under the hood, how can this all be applied in the point of the view of a programmer? Let's make a synthesis (without specific rationales).

- `<form>` is a link which can send more information to the server than a regular link like `<a>`
- `action` attribute of a form is roughly equal to `href` attribute of a regular link
- Submitting a form always loads a new page, this is the default action of the submission
- Any attempt to navigate to another page (including clicking links or submitting other forms, or setting `location.href` in JS) is prevented while a submit event is pending
- Programmer can interfere form submission by setting a *submit* event listener to the **form**
- If attribute-based form validation fails, attached submit event handler(s) is/are not executed
- A submit event handler can modify the current page and the data to submit, and it also can cancel the form submission
- Nevertheless what is done in a submit event handler, **the form is submitted when the handler execution is finished**, unless the handler cancels the default action of the submit event

What triggers a form submission then? There are multiple ways to start a form submission. All the elements below are so called submitter elements, those have "submit the form" as their default action:

1. `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`
2. `<input type="image" alt="Submit">`
3. `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`
4. `<button>Submit</button>`
5. Hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on active `<input type="date/number/password/search/tel/text/time/url/week">`
6. Calling `form.submit` method in JS

Notice the typeless `<button>` element, it's also a submit button by default, when placed inside a form.

#### Preventing the default action of an event

Some events have a default action, which is executed after the event handler function has finished. For example, the default action of `submit` event is to submit the form triggered the event. You can prevent the default action to be executed in the event handler by calling `preventDefault` method of the event object:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

`event` is either the object passed in the arguments of the handler, or the global `event` object.

Returning `false` from an *event handler function* doesn't prevent the form submission. This works with inline listeners only, when `return false;` is written in an `onsubmit` attribute.

In the past, the first three elements in the submitter element list above were "stronger" than the other elements. If you've attached a **click** listener to an input type of submit/image or a button type of submit, preventing the default action of the (click) event didn't prevent the form submission. Other elements could do that also within a `click` listener. This behavior has been changed after this answer was written, modern browsers can prevent form submission also in a click handler of the any submitter element. To prevent the submission in all cases (also in older browsers), you've to listen to `submit` event **on the form** instead of clicks on the submitter elements.

And again: `form.submit` method called in any script, will jump over all form validations and won't fire any submit events, it can't be cancelled via JS. It's notable, that this stands for the native `submit` method only, ex. jQuery's `.submit` isn't native, and it calls the attached submit handlers.

### Send data and stay on the current page

To send data and still stay on the current page can be achieved only by not submitting the form. There are multiple ways to prevent the submission. The simplest way is to not include a form in the markup at all, that makes a lot of extra work with data handling in JS, though. The best way is to prevent the default action of the submit event, any other way with a form would cause extra work, for example, triggering JS without a submitter element still provides detecting submissions made by #5 in the submitter elements list.

As the data won't go to a server without submitting, you need to send the data with JS. The technique to use is called AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml).

Here's a simple vanilla JS code example of sending data to the server, and staying on the current page. The code utilizes [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Typically the code is placed in a submit event handler of a form, as it is in the example below. You can make a request anywhere in the scripts on a page, and if a submit event is not involved, preventing the default action is not needed.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const data = new FormData(form);
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  xhr.open('POST', 'action_URL');
  xhr.addEventListener('load', e => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // The request was successful
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      // The request failed
      console.log(xhr.status);
    }
  });
  xhr.send(data);
});
```

The analogy to a form is scattered allover the code:

- control element values are included in `data` (`form` being a reference to an existing form element)
- `method` attribute is the first argument of `xhr.open`
- `action` attribute is the second argument of `xhr.open`
- `enctype` attribute is created by [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) constructor (defaults to "multipart/form-data")

The difference between AJAX and form submission is, that when getting a response for an AJAX call from the server, the JavaScript execution continues in the `load` handler of `xhr` instead of browser loading a new page when submitting a form. In that `load` handler you can do what ever you need with the data server sent as the response, or just redirect (also succesfully with a timeout). It's also possible to leave the load handler out of the code, when you don't need a notify of the request success/failure or any response data.

In modern browsers you can also use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make an AJAX request. Also, most of the commonly used frameworks (if not all) and many libraries (like jQuery), have their own (more or less simplified) implementations for various AJAX-based tasks.

#### Remarks

Due to the order of the tasks executed in the internal submit algorithm, the validation attributes are handled before calling the submit event handler(s). If any of the validations fails, the algorithm is cancelled. This means, that when the form validation fails, also the submit event handler(s) are not executed.

Validation based on the validation attributes is executed only after activating a submitter element, validation attributes are not affecting to an object created by `FormData` constructor, which can be created at any time, a submit event is not necessarily needed.

The `target` attribute of the form is ignored when creating a `FormData` object. An AJAX call always targets to the current page, it can't be redirected to another document.

It's not mandatory to send a FormData object, you can send any data you need, but it has to be formatted according to the `method` of the request.