# Console not displaying data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to display data in my console. For some reason it just flashes the result and refreshes the console. I am running the html file on server.

Code-

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" >
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="fetch">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#fetch').click(function(){
        var str = $("#fname").val();
        console.log(str);
        });
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to debug this. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior . You can make loggings persistent by ticking "Persist logs" on DevTools options.

Comment: It's because by clicking the button you submit the form which redirects the browser to the form's target. As you've not specified the `action` here, it effectively reloads the page as a POST request

Comment: What do you mean with "_I am running the html file on server_"? JavaScript on a HTML page is not run on a server. Do you mean you've loaded the file to a browser from a server (instead of running the file locally with file:// schema)?

Comment: Yes. On localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return false` to prevent reloading:

```js
$('#fetch').click(function(){
        var str = $("#fname").val();
        console.log(str);
        return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" >
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="fetch">
</form>
```

Another way to prevent the default behavior:

```js
$('#fetch').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = $("#fname").val();
        console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" >
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="fetch">
</form>
```

Comment: How will they get their data posted then?

Comment: @Teemu this not part of the question, but the same methods can be applied when sending the request.

Comment: @MajedBadawi if I make a post request on submit, it now throws an error as POST 405 not allowed.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the form submit, but more on how you are sending the request. You can add the code to the question or open another one

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the submit button will submit the form, and thus refresh the page, which is the reason why the console is clearing.

Since you're using jQuery, you can add `return false;` right after your `console.log(str);`, so the original action (here, the form submission) will be cancelled.

Comment: How will they get their data posted then?