# JS to enter a correct phrase before form allows to be submitted

Tags: javascript

I am trying for our contact page to allow submission only once a correct phrase is entered.
I have no idea how and tried the alert function. It alerts when the wrong phrase is entered, but still submits the form. Basically I am trying to prevent automated submission of our form.

The relevant code:

```
  **HTML:**

  <label for="phrase" class="p">Please enter "security" below</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="phrase" name="phrase" required></type><br>

   <input type="submit"; onclick="no_spam()"; value="Submit"></type>

  **JS:**

  function no_spam() {
  var spam = document.getElementById("phrase").value;
  if(spam !== "security") 
  {alert("Enter correct phrase")}
  }
```

Comment: You've to get familiar with [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior/63509329#63509329)

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at google recaptcha and try to use it.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Check out this resource: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Thank you. Pattern attribute works perfectly. Re recaptcha: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, was just curious how to get it to work. Now I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any JavaScript; it can be done entirely in HTML5 using the `pattern` attribute.

```html
<form>
  <label for="phrase" class="p">Please enter "security" below</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="phrase" name="phrase" required pattern="^security$" title="Enter correct phrase"></type><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></type>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are talking about submitting, I assume you also have a FORM tag.

```
<form action=...>
<input name=.... />
</form>
```

#1. Don't use onXXX event registration. This is a dangerous hackable feature in HTML/Javascript, one that is disallowed if you use a Content-Security-Policy. Instead, use

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  //validate your form. If not valid, call e.preventDefault();
});
```

The other thing you can do (assuming you are working in HTML 5) is use the `pattern` attribute to create a regex to make sure the input is valid. Using this attribute, the form will not submit if the field doesn't pass validation