# Function inside a function isn't working. Am I missing return statement?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to build it simple first before adding more fields. But these functions should be able to add fields to the div called to submit, receive values in them and pass it to an inside string. But for now, I am trying to make a function inside another work.

```html
<body>
    <form id="container">
        <div id="prim">
            <div id="opts">
                <input type="radio" id="blue" name="ISP" value="blue">
                <label for="Blue">Blue</label>    
                <input type="radio" id="red" name="ISP" value="red">    
                <label for="red">Red</label>
                <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="ISP" value="yellow">    
                <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate" id="enter">
    </form>
</body>
```

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('submit', function(f) {
  var line2 = '';
  document.getElementById("blue").addEventListener('click', function(a) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    console.log("blue");
    line2 = 'blue';
  })
  document.getElementById("red").addEventListener('click', function(b) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    console.log("red");
  })
  document.getElementById("yellow").addEventListener('click', function(c) {
    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(box);
    console.log("yellow");

  })
  var line1 = "My color is "
  var line3 = " and not any other."
  console.log(line1 + line2 + line3)
})
```

Comment: Why are you adding event listeners in a submit handler? A form is submitted, and a new page is loaded.

Comment: Event handlers will automatically be passed a reference to the `event` that triggered them so your `f`, `a`, `b`, and `c` arguments will each be that `event` reference. As such the standard is to name that argument `event`, `evt`, or `e`. Also, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Still learning man, all tutorials and online stuff

Comment: Are you really wanting to "submit" data to another page or do you just want a button that can be clicked which will kick off some code?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and add the relevant HTML so we can get a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus this application generates a text file that is made of the combination of different strings. That's why I use the submit event. When it is clicked, the text file is generated. And now I need to make it dynamic with radio buttons to choose the forms to be entered.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus I have added the simple HTML.

Comment: Based on your updated question, your `form` doesn't submit data anywhere and I don't see anything that would create a text file. "Submitting" means "sending" the data to another page, where it is processed as input.

Comment: The part about the text file is functioning elsewhere. This is just an abstract, not the main project, so I can meddle without worrying about destroying my first working project. My current issue is the functions inside functions. @ScottMarcus

Comment: The issue is that your event handlers should not be set up inside of a `submit` event and your HTML doesn't show any submitting going on. It would be best to show all of the relevant code so we can understand the best way to help.

Comment: When you submit, you submit and the current page processing stops and the resource you've submitted to takes over. Adding additional code inside the `submit` event handler that updates the current page or sets up event handlers on the current page wouldn't work, because you are about to leave the current page.

Comment: Your code is working fine, but submitting the form reloads the page (as there's no action attribute in the form element). [Forms are just links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519), which to you can attach more information than to an `a` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to need to actually "submit" data here. You just need to process some input upon the click of a button. Because of that, you shouldn't be using a "submit" button, rather you just need a "button".

Next, the event handlers should not be nested. In fact, you can leverage ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to reduce the number of event handlers that are needed.

```js
var line2 = '';

// Get references to the elements you know you'll need just once
// rather than inside of the event handler that may run several
// times.
const result = document.getElementById("result");

// Instead of setting up pretty much identical event handlers
// for each of the radio buttons, just set up one for the parent
// of the radio buttons and handle the clicks there.
document.getElementById("opts").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Event handlers are automatically passed a reference to the 
  // event that triggered them and that event object can lead
  // you to the actual element that triggered the event in the
  // first place with: event.target
  result.textContent = "";
  console.log(event.target.id);
  line2 = event.target.id;
});

document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener('click', function(f) {
  console.log("My color is " + line2 + " and not any other.");
});
```

```html
    <form id="container">
        <div id="prim">
            <div id="opts">
                <input type="radio" id="blue" name="ISP" value="blue">
                <label for="Blue">Blue</label>    
                <input type="radio" id="red" name="ISP" value="red">    
                <label for="red">Red</label>
                <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="ISP" value="yellow">    
                <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Generate" id="enter">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I really appreciate this! If I may ask, what if I need to use the event.target as a condition to perform a function. Is this the right code?

 if (event.target.id = "blue")
    {
        console.log("blue");

    }
    else if (event.target.id = "red")
    {
        console.log("red");

    }
    else if (event.target.id = "yellow")
    {
        console.log("yellow");

    }

Comment: @AhmadFathy You're welcome. Yes, you could write a conditional statement just like that if you needed to. And, don't forget to up vote the answer and mark it as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Comment: @AhmadFathy One thing though, in JavaScript `=` is used for assignment, not comparison. So, to check `event.target.id` against, say "red", you'd use `===` as in: `if(event.target.id === "red") { ...`