# Button onclick not allowing my window to appear

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a tough time following [this](https://www.cssscript.com/simple-modal-window-with-background-blur-effect/) little tutorial on how to create a modal window when a button is clicked.

Not sure if my html is correct (the modal window is at the very bottom), but when I click on save list button nothing happens, only a refresh. I'm using Visual Studio Code with the live server plugin if that has anything to do with it. It did work when using a simple alert('hello').

For reference here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/OMantid/pen/pobLKWx

HTML

```
<form id='myModal' class= 'Modal is-hidden is-visuallyHidden'>
    <div class='Modal-content'>
        <label for='list-name'>Name:</label>
        <input type='text' name='list-name' id='list-name'>
        <div class='modal-btn-container'>
            <button name='save-listName'>Save</button>
            <button name='cancel-listSave' class='cancel-btn'>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
    //Get the modal
let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

//Get the main container and the body
let main = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
let header = document.getElementsByTagName('header');

//Get the open button
let saveBtn = document.getElementById('save-btn');

saveBtn.onclick = function() {
    modal.className = 'Modal is-visuallyHidden';
    setTimeout(function() {
        main.className = 'is-blurred';
        modal.className = 'Modal';
    }, 100);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `form` element is a link, and a typeless `button` element submits the form. Hence your page is reloaded, becuse missing `action` attribute of the form defaults to the current document location.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, would any of the actions prevent a page from refreshing? I think that could be the cause of why my classes aren't being named properly for the modal window to show up.

Comment: No, but you can do it in JS, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior/63509329#63509329