# Text display and gone again in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is happening. I'm inputting value for the operation to solve but when it displays the result it displays but in a brief time only.

```
function add(){
        var num1 = document.getElementById('fnum').value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById('snum').value;
        var ans = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

        document.getElementById('res').value = ans;
    }
<form>
  1st Number:<input type="text" id="fnum" name="Num1" /><br>
  2nd Number:<input type="text" id="snum" name="Num2" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Add" id="button1" name="button" onclick="add()"/>
  The result is:<input type="text" id="res" name="res" readonly="true" /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please get familiar with the elements you're workin withg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior/63509329#63509329

Comment: Simply, do not use <form>.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding HTML Form Element behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the `<form>` tag with a `<button type="submit">`, the form is submitted.

So what's happening is that your `onclick` event is handled, but when that's done, the form is still submitted. You have multiple ways of fixing this:

- Don't use `<form>`
- Change the `<button>` type to `button`
- Handle the form submit in JavaScript
- Cancel the click event

Here's a working version without a `<form>` tag and `<button type="button">`:

```js
function add() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById('fnum').value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById('snum').value;
    var ans = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

    document.getElementById('res').value = ans;
}
```

```html
  1st Number:<input type="text" id="fnum" name="Num1" /><br>
  2nd Number:<input type="text" id="snum" name="Num2" /><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="button1" name="button" onclick="add()" />
  The result is:<input type="text" id="res" name="res" readonly="true" /><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because your button is a submit component,
change :

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="button1" name="button" onclick="add()"/>
```

to

```
<button type="button" value="Add" id="button1" name="button" onclick="add()">add</button>
```

a submit component used to submit your form so you'll need a valid action in your form for that.
or you can use onsubmit event for your form to prevent default form action