# can not sent appended FormData to php-file from simple html-form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following form html:

```
<form method="POST" id="checkoutform" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="order">
   ...
  <input type="submit" onclick="return clickSubmitbuttonOnce(this);">
```

My clickSubmitbuttonOnce(button) is:

```
  var t = document.getElementById("checkoutform");  
  var formData = new FormData(t);
      formData.append("payment", "Payment");
  for (var p of formData) {
        console.log("%s : %s",p[0],p[1]);
  }

  t.submit();
```

If I pass this to file the print_r($_POST,true); do not gives the appended payment. Only the action-field is given. The console-statement says it is given.
Whats wrong. Does need FormData() mandatory an Ajax request?
How can I achieve to pass the payment-field?

Comment: You seem to submit the form element assigned to `t` and not the formdata object that holds the new data?

Comment: "_Does need FormData() mandatory an Ajax request?_" More or less yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519

Comment: aren't the formData = new FormData(t) not assigned to t? I assume the  parameter < t > is doing this.

Comment: No, the form control values are only copied to `formData` object, the form and the object are not linked to each other. You can also add `input type="hidden" name="payment">` to the form, and then give that an approriate value, and submit the form. That way you wouldn't need `formData` object at all.

Comment: the spec says: You can also append additional data to the FormData object between retrieving it from a form by passing the form. I think the thing here is to pass the formData-object and not the form.

Comment: Yes, adding an element to the form was just an alternative suggestion (the "_or less_" part in my previous comment). Like said, forms and `formData` objects are not linked, and `formData` doesn't have `submit` method, the only way to send `formData` to a server is AJAX.