# Execute a function , after form successfully submitted

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, promise, settimeout

I'm trying to alter the registration procedure that WordPress is using by adding another 'step.'

Since I added foreign key constraints in my database tables, wp_users need to be filled first and after executing the rest of the code.

My current code for WordPress form submit interruption is:

```
jQuery("#registerform").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let self = jQuery(this);
    self.unbind().submit();
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (jQuery("#registerusingwebauthn").is(":checked")) {

            let username = jQuery("#user_login").val();
            initializeCredentialType({
                authenticationMethod: "webauthn"
            });
            webauthn_registration(username,null)
                .then(function(e){
                    alert(e);})
                .catch(function (e){
                    console.log(e)});
        }
    },60000);

});
```

The `self.unbind().submit();` part it's used because the wp_users table must be filled in first, or else a violation of constraints will occur.

The webauthn_registration is returning a new Promise and it's defined as follows:

```
const webauthn_registration=(username,type)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        // some variable definition here//
        if (username === ""){
            reject("Error: Username not given");
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'username': username},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (error){reject(error);},
            success: function(serverregdata){
                // some variable definition here//
                navigator.credentials.create({publicKey: serverregdata})
                    .then(function(credentials){
                        // some variable definition here//
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            error: function (error){alert(error);reject(error);},
                            success:function(success){alert(success);resolve('success');}
                        })
                    });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that `setTimeout()` doesn't wait until the promise that `webauthn_registration` is resolved and reloads the page before `webauthn_registration` is finished.

For some more information (if needed), AJAX is interacting with a python server, and the Tables Constraints are as follow:

wp_users.username is a foreign key to webauthn_users.
webauthn_users.id is a foreign key to webauthn_credentials.

PS
The `webauthn_registration` function was working fine in a static HTML website that the submit function was directly linked to `webauthn_registration.`

Comment: You can't submit a form and stay on the same page, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior/63509329#63509329

Comment: My intention is not to stay on the same page forever, it's to execute some function after the form submission and before the redirection to the next screen. If I correctly understood how the `setTimeout` method works, It can wait a certain amount of time(and execute some code while waiting) and then continue with whatever needs to be done.

Comment: It doesn't matter, a form is a link, and when it's submitted, a new page is loaded immediately, and everything what is running asynchronously (including timeouts) in JS is aborted. You simply can't change that behavior.

Comment: You can either send the form data with AJAX, or put the line `self.unbind().submit();` into the timed function, which probably is not suitable for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I would suggest to try the following trick:

```
$('form').one('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your things ...

    // and when you done:
    $(this).submit();
});
```