# How to stay on the same page after POST action is called in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple online form that calls a PHP script on submit.

```
<form name="newform" id="regForm" action="../includes/submit.inc.php" method="post">
```

When the submit button is clicked the site URL in the browser changes to http://example.com/includes/submit.inc.php and the page is blank.

I want to display a Thank you message after form is submitted and I want the URL to remain http://example.com

I've tried using JS to hide the main container of my website and enabling a DIV with the thank you message.

```
function submit() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("success").style.display = "inline";
}

document.getElementById('regForm').onsubmit = function () {
    var terms = document.getElementById('consentBox');

    if (!terms.checked) {
        showWarnings(warnings);
        return false;
    }
    submit();
    return true;
    
};
```

This kind of works I can see the thank you message for a split second but then the browser goes to http://example.com/includes/submit.inc.php and the page is blank. I really want to avoid redirecting to another .php file. I know I could do something like this:

```
header( "location: ../success.php", true, 301 );
```

But prefer to display the message on the same page. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You could have all your logic inside the same file, in which case you would submit to the same page and could display the message after submission. 2) You could use AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior

Comment: @El_Vanja 1) I want some separation 2) I will research AJAX

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. Will take a look

Comment: Do you want to avoid going to another page or do you want _no page reloading_ at all? The first leads to keep the logic inside the same file, the second would lead to an asynchronous call, handled with AJAX. For an entry level I would start with the first approach.

Comment: @Amessihel I want to remain on the same page and keep the file separation so first option is out. I will research AJAX. Thanks.

Comment: Actually you can write the submission logic in a separate file and include it with `require()` if needed. The real difference between those solutions is how you handle your submission (synchronously or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can add post php code in the same page where you written the main code.
For example-

```
<form name="newform" id="regForm" action="inex.php" method="post">

<?php
//and your php post code here 
?>
```

Comment: It still will be a new document in the browser, though. That means the state of the previous page is replaced with a new state, JS variables, possible DOM manipulations etc, they're all gone.

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved through the use of AJAX and the serialization of the form. This is written with the assumption that the php script returns a status message (html block looking to be displayed) upon successful completion. This can also be helpful for error handling, in the event there is an issue within the php script. This example makes use of the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/).

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="input1">
  <input type="text" name="input2">
</form>
```

```js
// Using jQuery 

$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {

  //Prevent Default
  e.preventDefault();

  // Gather Form Values into Array  
  var values = {};
  $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(_, kv) {
    values[kv.name] = kv.value;
  });

  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "pathToFile/formHandlingFile.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
        vals: values
      }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
     
     $('#main').hide()
     $('#success').html(data)
     $('#success').show()

    })

});
```

Comment: Hi Aiden, this is helpful. When I submit the form it reaches the  $('#success').show() line but data is not being submitted to my database. I wonder if this has anything to do with the location of my php file. The structure is root/includes/submit.inc.php and for index.php it is root/index.php url attribute is currently url: "includes/submit.inc.php" Is this correct?

Comment: Hey Mr. T - This does sound correct to me. Since the path is handled in the ajax request, the outputted information from the php script does not need to include any path information. In other words you can simply echo information out with the php script and it should be return in the data variable. I would make sure you can see the #success element with static information in the DOM. Also make sure your passing data to the PHP script with POST.