# how to store dynamically created checked checkbox in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having  dynamically created checkbox...
I want that checked value from the checkbox should be stored in one array...
I am Facing the following Problems...

*

```
var checkedvalue=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
   If I alert the value of checkedvalue It given undefined
```

- If I have console.log the final variable console.log(array); It given the
  ["on"] in the console.log if the value is checked.

I didn't get the actual value.My code is given below. I don't know what is the mistake I did. Anyone could you please help me.
Thanks in Advance

```
<input type="Submit" Value="add" onclick="searchinput()">
--------------
function searchinput()
{
var li=document.createElement("li");
//creating checkbox
var label=document.createElement('label');
label.className="lab_style";
li.appendChild(label);
    var check=document.createElement('input');
    check.type="checkbox";
    check.name="check_bo";  
    li.appendChild(check);
    check.addEventListener('click', function() {

 var array=[];
  var checkedvalue=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    alert(checkedvalue.value);
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedvalue.length; i++) {
    array.push(checkedvalue[i].value);
    console.log(array);
    }
    
}, false);
}
```

Comment: You need to get familiar with [how `form` element works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519).

Comment: You aren't giving the checkboxes you create a value either

Comment: ^-- And even if there were the values assigned, that's not much of worth, the values will be the same despite of the checkbox being checked or not.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? It looks like you'd like to stay on the page, and only add a checkbox, and create an array of the values of the checked checkboxes. Apart from the submission issue, that's exactly what your code does. What is the "value" you're expecting instead of the default `on`?

Comment: @Teemu Actually I am the beginner . I just want to do my  checklist. .I don't want to redirect to another page.. Actually I need the value in checkbox which I have given in the input box.. That parts are working so I didn't mentioned here. Thanks

Comment: Just use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` to fire the JS and not submit the form. Then you need a relation between the checkbox and text input. Maybe they're siblings, we don't know, because you haven't provided your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form with a bunch of checkboxes and once the form is submitted you want to have the values of all the checkboxes which are checked stored in an array then you can do it like this.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const arr = [];

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  checkboxes.forEach(chbox => {
    if (chbox.checked) {
      arr.push(chbox.value)
    }
  })
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Apple:
  <input type="checkbox" value="apple" name="test"></label>
  <label>Mango:
  <input type="checkbox" value="mango" name="test"></label>
  <label>Banana:
  <input type="checkbox" value="banana" name="test"></label>
  <label>Grape:
  <input type="checkbox" value="grape" name="test"></label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's still a problem with the code. Originally this is run when a form is submitted, there won't be time to actually check the box.

Comment: @Teemu So, there are a bunch of checkboxes in a form and once the form is submitted I want to store the values of all the checked checkboxes in an array, Is that what we are trying to achieve?

Comment: Once your form is submitted, you're redirected to a new page (or the current page is reloaded), everything you do on the current page is gone.

Comment: @Teemu You can prevent the default behavior of the form, else you need to get the data in the backend (for ex: using a POST route)

Comment: @Teemu I've updated my answer have a look please.

Comment: The question doesn't tell, but probably OP doesn't actually even want to submit the form, they want just to add a check box when clicking on a button.

Answer (score 0):

one of the problems you are facing is that

```
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

returns a `NodeList` and `value` is not a property on an `NodeList` object. That is why you are seeing "undefined" in your alert.
Changing as little of your code as possible, I think this should work:

```
function searchinput()
{
    var li=document.createElement("li");
    //creating checkbox
    var label=document.createElement('label');
    label.className="lab_style";
    li.appendChild(label);
    var check=document.createElement('input');
    check.type="checkbox";
    check.name="check_bo";  
    li.appendChild(check);
    check.addEventListener('click', function() {

        var array=[];
        var checkedvalue = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkedvalue.length; i++) {
            if(checkedvalue[i].checked) {
                array.push(checkedvalue[i].value);
            }
        }
    
    }, false);
}
```