# Cannot submit form with the usage of Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue about submitting a form via ajax and open a modal Dialog after the ajax function is completed successfully. When I click a submitButton, the process cannot be completed.

Where is the problem in an ajax method or anywhere?

How can I fix it?

Here is my form HTML part.

```
<form id="contactForm" role="form" class="php-email-form">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="nameSurname" class="form-control" id="nameSurname" placeholder="Name Surname" required>
                            </div>                        

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        

     <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
                        </div>                   

     <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                        </div>                   

   <div class="my-3"></div>                     

   <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" data-bs-toggle="modal">Submit</button> <!-- data-bs-target="#modalDialog"-->
                        </div>                     

</form>
```

Here is my modal part.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @ViewBag.Success
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#submitButton").click(function () {

                var nameSurname = $("#nameSurname").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var subject = $("#subject").val();
                var message = $("#message").val();

                var form = $('#contactForm');
                var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Contract/',
                    data: {
                        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                        nameSurname: nameSurname, email: email, subject: subject, message: message
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#modalDialog").show();
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert('custom message. Error: ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
    })

</script>
```

Here is my Contract action in Home Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Contract(string nameSurname = null, string email = null, string subject = null, string message = null)
        {

        if (nameSurname != null && email != null) 
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpClient.Port = 587;

            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmail address", "gmail address password");
            // smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // uncomment if you don't want to use the network credentials
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = message;

            //Setting From , To and CC
            mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("gmail address"));

            smtpClient.Send(mail);
            ViewBag.Success = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Error";
        }
        return View();
}
```

Comment: The form is submitted, and your server responses with a new page (or with the current page, if you haven't defined `action` attribute for the form). Loading a new page aborts the ongoing AJAX call.

Comment: Html part is incomplete or you don't have any form in it.

Comment: @Teemu I updated my post.

Comment: @Adlorem I updated my post.

Comment: I've already described the issue in my comment above.

Comment: See [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519), even the question introduces a very similar problem.

Comment: @Teemu I tested your code but it didn't work. The reason for it is related with refreshing a current page. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you debugged to see how far the request goes in the controller or if it hits the controller at all?

Comment: @LukeWeaver I already debugged it. Modal Dialog screen cannot be opened.

Comment: Are you returning a RedirectToAction every time for the Ajax call? Redirect to action will automatically redirect your page and so the Ajax call wouldn’t have time to run the success function.

Comment: @LukeWeaver I used `return View()` to show modal but it didn't work. That's why I tried to use this but it didn't work either. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Return Ok(); anything involving view or action loads/reloads the page. Also, remove the if (data != null) if you aren’t going to send any c# objects back or else the modal open function won’t be invoked. I can type up a full explanation in an answer if that solves your problem

Comment: Also I’ve only ever used Ok() in API controllers so you might need to add a using statement for an mvc controller but I doubt it.

Comment: @LukeWeaver Is it possible to write the function?

Comment: @LukeWeaver I used `Ok` but there is an error in the Contract function. How can I fix it? Its error is that OK doesn't exist.

Comment: If you’re using visual studio, right click the Ok method and the suggested actions should have something like “include [namespace]”. If it doesn’t show you that, then I’ll search for a manual solution.

Comment: @LukeWeaver My problem is that I cannot show modal dialog because the page refreshes after the Contract process is completed without any error. I hope you can help me solve my issue.

Comment: Check out my answer below, I’ll edit it to include which namespace you should include with using to be able to access Ok()

Comment: @LukeWeaver Contract page cannot be opened and a modal dialog cannot be triggered to open after implementing your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contract", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }, new { @id = "ajaxForm" }))
{

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="nameSurname" class="form-control" id="nameSurname" placeholder="Name Surname" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="my-3"></div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button> <!-- data-bs-target="#modalDialog"-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Contract(string nameSurname = null, string email = null, string subject = null, string message = null)
{
  // do what is necessary
  if (nameSurname != null && email != null) 
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtpClient.Port = 587;

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmail address", "gmail address password");
        // smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // uncomment if you don't want to use the network credentials
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = message;

        //Setting From , To and CC
        mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("gmail address"));

        smtpClient.Send(mail)
        return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
    else  // return result 
    {
        return Json("Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }      
}
```

We have to create OnSuccess function in view to do something with result;

```
<script>
       function OnSuccess(data) {
            if (data == 'Success') {
                $("#modalDialog").modal('show');
            }
        }

        function OnFailure(data) {
            //log failure
        }

        function OnBegin() {
            // do something on begin
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I tested your code but it didn't work. The reason for it is related with refreshing a current page and it leads to send an email to my defined email. How can I fix it?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it is simple now?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

After I realized Ok() isn’t accessible in an MVC controller I found this solution which does essentially the same thing.

In your controller, change:

```
return RedirectToAction(“contract”);
```

To:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

RedirectToAction() and View() will by default load or refresh a page while a 200 (OK) response will just return a success status code.