# javascript submit form in then block and return false from a non-async function using swal

Tags: javascript, promise, sweetalert

I am trying to submit form using  `onsubmit return myFunc()` but I also want to use swall inside the function. Here is how my code looks like.
 `<form action="./script.php" onsubmit"return myFunc()"> </form>`

```
let userName = $("#userName")
// use some validation here and finally

swal({
     title: "Are you sure",
     text: "Some Text"
     buttons: ['No', 'Yes']
     }).then((result) { 
         if(result) {
              console.log("Here we are!! ")
              return true
             // This is when I want the form to be submitted other wise return false
         } else {return false}        
    })
return false;
}
```

What happens is  that the function return false and never executes the code in the .then block.

Comment: There's a syntax error in `then`, `function` keyword or  `=>` is missing. You can't use the return value of the inline listener for the task when you're having an async condition preventing/allowing the submission. You've to prevent the default action in all cases, and if `swal` result is "Yes", then submit the form in `then` callback function.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show some code or how do I call the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some syntax errors in the code. `function` keyword or `=>` is missing in `then` argument, and a comma is missing from the parameter list of `swal()`. Apart from these, the logic doesn't work when mixing synchronous and asynchronous tasks.

The actual event listener is the content of `onsubmit` attribute, that calls `myFunc` and returns the value returned from that function to the internal event handler. `swal()` call returns a promise, which then is handled in a callback function passed to `then`. `swal` call is thus asynchronous, and the callback function is executed after a user really clicks a button in the alert box. At that time, `myFunc` has already finished and returned `false`.

To fix the issue, you've to prevent the default action of the form submission in all cases, and if `swal` result is "Yes", then submit the form in the callback function passed to `then`. Something like this:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');

function myFunc(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form submission in any case
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure",
    text: "Some Text",
    buttons: ['No', 'Yes']
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      console.log('Submit the form.')
      // form.submit(); // Uncomment this line to submit the form     
    } else {
      console.log('No submission.')
    }
  });
}

form.addEventListener('submit', myFunc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `HTMLFormElement#submit()` can skip the `submit` event. I thought this would run in an infinite asynchronous loop.

Comment: @FZs I'm not familiar with SweetAlert, do you mean calling `swal` will cause an infinite loop?

Comment: No, it won't. Just I thought it will, because I thought `.submit()` will call the `onsubmit` event listener again. But it does not, so everything's fine!

Comment: @FZs OK. As you already have noticed, `submit` method of the form element doesn't trigger the submit event. You can read more about how form submission works in [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519).