# Correct output shows for a only millisecond in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get values from HTML but every time I click the submit button there is a glitch. The output is showing as expected but only for a millisecond. I'm new to coding, kindly guide me.

HTML:

```js
var my_name = "harhu";
var my_password = "harshali";

function my_form() {
    var a = document.getElementById("nameForm").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("passForm").value;
    
    if (a == my_name && b == my_password) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Access granted! Welcome!";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Access denied! Try again.";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Values from HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To receive values from HTML</h1>

    <form>
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" id="nameForm" value="">
        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="text" id="passForm">
        <button onclick="my_form()">Submit</button>
        <p id="result">-------</p>
    </form>

    <script src="valuesFromHtml.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is working, but the output is shown only for a mere second, it's a glitch of sorts? The code is working seamlessly when I use the `event.preventDefault()` but it should work without it too, right?

Comment: It shouldn't work without preventing the default action. `form` is a link, and when submitting a form, browser navigates to the URL specified in `action` attribute of the form. If the attribute is omitted, the current location of the page is used.

Comment: The form is submitting (ie redirecting away from the current URL). `e.preventDefault()` prevents that from happening.

Comment: @Teemu yes its working , when i omitted the <form> tag , thank you very much! :D

Comment: @HarshaliDeshmukh why not keep the element and have `preventDefault()`? I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Andy , apologies ,  I'm yet to understand the complete use of it as I'm still learning and in the course(online) that i am viewing it  worked well without the preventDefalut() ,  i  realize now the problem was with the button tag. it should've been "<input type="button" onclick="my_form()" name="Submit" value="Submit" />"

Comment: @HarshaliDeshmukh [Form element thoroughly explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519).

Answer (score 1):

I thing you should change your button tag to input with type button

Before:

```
<button onclick="my_form()">Submit</button>
```

After:

```
<input type="button" onclick="my_form()" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a glitch `button` tab will submit the form by default. That's the reason you see the color temporarily.

You can change the component from `<button>` to `<input type="button">` as mentioned in the other answer.

Or

In your button tag `onclick` event, add `return false;` at the end. this will be helpful when CSS is based on the element type.

```html
<button onclick="my_form();return false;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: the return false; seems to be working perfectly too , thank you very much for your help!