# Make form button prevent default and run function instead

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm very new to frontend development and I'm working on a form that runs a `getPlot()` function on submit. After some research I noticed that the default behaviour for forms is to send a GET request with the form's data. To avoid this, I created the following function:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var csrf_token = document.querySelector('meta[name="_token"]').content;
    const form = document.getElementById('formDistrict');
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        getPlot();

});
```

The thing is, this has an erratic behaviour: sometimes it runs getPlot(), plotting what I want, and sometimes it sends a GET request with the form's data, with no discernible pattern whatsoever. I'm guessing the fix is simple, but I wasn't able to find anything. What I want is my button to always run getPlot() using the form's info on click. This is the html code if it helps:

```
    <div class="input-group m-3 ui-widget" >


        {{ render_form(params.form) }}


        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </div>


</form>
```

Where params.form is defined here:

class SearchForm(FlaskForm):

```
form_comuna = StringField('', id='district_autocomplete',
                       validators=[DataRequired(),
                                   Length(min=4, max=20)],
                          render_kw={'class': 'form-control ui-autocomplete-input'}
                          )
submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

If it's important, this also uses JQuery UI's autocomplete. Can add more code if needed.

Thanks a lot

EDIT: forgot to add I can't use inline JS because of CSP policies.

EDIT 2: This is getPlot()'s code, it uses fetch:

```
function getPlot() {

    var csrf_token = document.querySelector('meta[name="_token"]').content;

    var district= document.getElementById('district_autocomplete').value;

    console.log('selected district is ', district);
    fetch('/get_graph', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(district),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data_geojson => {
            // Plot graph:
            drawGraph(data_geojson)
            toggleDiv()

       })

        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Calling `event.preventDefault` works as it is. If the form is submitted occasionally, it's not due to this code (providing all the elements are available at the time the script is run). You've to search the code base for other submit handlers, most likely there's some code submitting the form using JS (that way your submit handler is not called, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329)

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I'll check that. Also I found a question where they mentioned fetch might have to do with it